# Populate WordPress Elementor form fields with Post values

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post, elementor

I have a custom form = in WordPress. When I submit form I need to display Post values Inside elemntor Form Field.

```
<form action="get-my-solution" method="post">
<input class="checkbox-booking" type="text" name="ant" value="ants">
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

In elementor Form I added a HTML widget. inside that added

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $ant = isset($_POST['ant']) ? $_POST['ant'] : '';
}
```

How to diplay post values inside the form field?

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for https://elementor.com/help/dynamic-request-parameter-pro/